# minimum update time in phoneGap App with watchPosition or getCurrentPosition?

Tags: iphone, cordova, geolocation, gps

I am having some trouble when update GPS location very fast, I need update location every 100ms. In my solutions I observe that the GPS location will update every second and not faster :(
I've try with setInterval:

```
function localize(){


    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {


        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

                                                 var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
                                                 element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude         + '<br />' +
                                                 'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude        + '<br />' +
                                                 'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude         + '<br />' +
                                                 'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy         + '<br />' +
                                                 'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '<br />' +
                                                 'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading          + '<br />' +
                                                 'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed            + '<br />' +
                                                 'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp               + '<br />';
                                                 },function(error){
                                                 alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                                                       'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
                                                 }, { maximumAge:100, timeout:100, enableHighAccuracy:true  });

    }else{
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }

}
localize();
setInterval(localize, 100);
}
```

with setTimeout:

```
localize();
function localize(){


    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {


        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

                                                 var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
                                                 element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude         + '<br />' +
                                                 'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude        + '<br />' +
                                                 'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude         + '<br />' +
                                                 'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy         + '<br />' +
                                                 'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '<br />' +
                                                 'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading          + '<br />' +
                                                 'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed            + '<br />' +
                                                 'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp               + '<br />';
                                                 },function(error){
                                                 alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                                                       'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
                                                 }, { maximumAge:100, timeout:100, enableHighAccuracy:true  });
        setTimeout(localize, 100);
    }else{
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }

}

setInterval(localize, 100);
}
```

or whatchPosition:

```
localize();
function localize(){


    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {


        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){

                                                 var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
                                                 element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude         + '<br />' +
                                                 'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude        + '<br />' +
                                                 'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude         + '<br />' +
                                                 'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy         + '<br />' +
                                                 'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '<br />' +
                                                 'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading          + '<br />' +
                                                 'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed            + '<br />' +
                                                 'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp               + '<br />';
                                                 },function(error){
                                                 alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                                                       'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
                                                 }, { maximumAge:100, timeout:100, enableHighAccuracy:true  });
        setTimeout(localize, 100); //with or without
    }else{
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }

}


}
```

I've tried with or without maximumAge and timeout option.
My device is iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPS devices in consumer phones update not more than once a second.
You will not get a 100ms interval, whatever you do.

So change your algorithm (interpolate) to work with 1 s.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Gps can't send an update up to 1s.
And I find this in the Android project made by Cordova. I think this can help you. Maybe it's the same thing in IOS project ?

I just discover one masive problem in Cordova/PhoneGap : - When you open the Android project built by cordova (in commandline), the requestUpdate is set at ..... 60 Seconds !!!!!!!!!!! You have a new Location every Minute ! Evenif you use GPS (enableHighAccuracy="true"). So try to set this at 1000 where you find LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER in org.apache.cordova.geolocation package -> GPSListener class !

Coco